# Why can't I su when if I am in the wheel group in OpenBSD?

Tags: su

Using a

```
OpenBSD 5.4 (GENERIC) #37: Tue Jul 30 15:24:05 MDT 2013
```

**I created a new user named "bela" and added it to the wheel group**:

```
# adduser
Use option ``-silent'' if you don't want to see all warnings and questions.

Reading /etc/shells
Check /etc/master.passwd
Check /etc/group

Ok, let's go.
Don't worry about mistakes. There will be a chance later to correct any input.
Enter username []: bela
Enter full name []: 
Enter shell csh ksh nologin sh [ksh]: 
Uid [1000]: 
Login group bela [bela]: 
Login group is ``bela''. Invite bela into other groups: guest no 
[no]: 
Login class authpf bgpd daemon default staff [default]: 
Enter password []: 
Enter password again []: 

Name:        bela
Password:    ****
Fullname:    bela
Uid:         1000
Gid:         1000 (bela)
Groups:      bela 
Login Class: default
HOME:        /home/bela
Shell:       /bin/ksh
OK? (y/n) [y]: y
Added user ``bela''
Copy files from /etc/skel to /home/bela
Add another user? (y/n) [y]: n
Goodbye!
# id bela
uid=1000(bela) gid=1000(bela) groups=1000(bela)
# vi /etc/group  
# grep bela /etc/group                                                                                                                                                                                      
wheel:*:0:root,bela
bela:*:1000:
# id bela
uid=1000(bela) gid=1000(bela) groups=1000(bela), 0(wheel)
# exit
```

The 127.0.0.1 is used because of running the OpenBSD in a Virtual machine:

```
ssh bela@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
bela@127.0.0.1's password: 
$ id
uid=1000(bela) gid=1000(bela) groups=1000(bela), 0(wheel)
$ su
Password:
Sorry
$ echo $?
1
$ exit
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
root@127.0.0.1's password: 
Last login: Mon Jan 13 07:46:26 2014 from 10.0.2.2
# cd /var/log                                                                                                                                                                                           
# cat authlog 
Jan 13 07:44:03 a sshd[28057]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jan 13 07:44:03 a sshd[28057]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jan 13 07:44:43 a login: ROOT LOGIN (root) ON ttyC0
Jan 13 07:46:15 a sshd[7284]: Did not receive identification string from 10.0.2.2
Jan 13 07:46:26 a sshd[11416]: Accepted password for root from 10.0.2.2 port 50734 ssh2
Jan 13 07:50:13 a sshd[11416]: Received disconnect from 10.0.2.2: 11: disconnected by user
Jan 13 07:50:24 a sshd[3083]: Connection closed by 10.0.2.2 [preauth]
Jan 13 07:50:28 a sshd[20344]: Accepted password for bela from 10.0.2.2 port 50751 ssh2
Jan 13 07:50:38 a su: **BAD SU** bela to root on /dev/ttyp0
Jan 13 07:50:46 a sshd[12615]: Received disconnect from 10.0.2.2: 11: disconnected by user
Jan 13 07:50:51 a sshd[3046]: Accepted password for root from 10.0.2.2 port 50753 ssh2
#
```

**My question:** Why can't I su to root with the "bela" user? The password for the user is simple, can't mess up.

Comment: we agrea that you need to use the root password and not the user password to log as root ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem there is that su asks for the user's password to which you want to switch, thus in your case it asks for root's password, not bela's. If you want to be able to become root with user's password (bela in your case), use [sudo](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sudo&sektion=8).